# Using a factory method with Inversion of control when class type is not known at runtime

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a question about IOC and when I don't know the class to be instantiated at run-time. For example, I have a few types of View classes. (HtmlView, CsvView, PDFView, etc ) that implement my view interface. The type of view class that I need is determined by user input ( a string in the DB ). I am leaning to using a `ViewFactory` class that has a make method, the problem is that this will be hiding the View dependency because I only need a `ViewFactory`.

```php
   class ViewFactory{
        public function make($viewType){
              if($viewType == 'html'){
                 $view = new HtmlView();
              }
              // ...
              return $view   
        }
   } 

   class ReportGenerator{
           public function constructor(Array $data, ViewFactory $viewFactory, String $viewType ){
                 $this->data = $data;
                 $this->view = $viewFactory($viewType);
           }
           public function generate(){
                  return $this->view->render($this->data)
           }
   }
```

It seems to me unclear that `ReportGenerator` depends on a base `ViewInterface`. Is there a better way, without using a static method.

Comment: Don't pass in a string as `$viewType`, pass in the typehinted interface  of the view. Although you're using the viewFactory to create the view itself and that clearly means that the `ReportGenerator` doesn't deal with actually picking which class should be instantiated, it feels odd to put a viewFactory inside a concrete class. I'll write this as an answer soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ViewInterface {

  public function render();
}

class HtmlView implements ViewInterface {

  const HTML_VIEW = 'html';

  public function render() {
    // TODO: Implement render() method.
  }
}

class AnotherView implements ViewInterface {

  const ANOTHER_VIEW = 'another';

  public function render() {
    // TODO: Implement render() method.
  }

}

class ViewFactory {

  public static function make($viewType) { // this could also be static
    // or use a construct, whichever strikes your fancy
    if ('html' == $viewType) { // fan of Yoda metod, I am
      $view = new HtmlView();
    }
    // ...
    return $view;
  }
}

class ReportGenerator {

  private $data;
  private $view;

  public function constructor(array $data, ViewInterface $view) {
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->view = $view;
  }

  public function generate() {
    return $this->view->render($this->data);

  }
}


$view = ViewFactory::make(HtmlView::HTML_VIEW);


$report = new ReportGenerator([], $view);
```

---

Instead of letting the ReportGenerator deal with anything view related, which it must never do, simply pass in the already created view.

The view itself should be created outside of ReportGenerator(or any other class for that matter - except the ViewFactory).

In the ViewFactory you can always add other methods to deal with the logic of creating new views.

Comment: “or any other part for that matter” well that’s the tricky part isn’t it. Where do you suggest putting it? It needs to know which type of view to create and that knowledge comes from user input so I imagine you’d have to place it in a controller for example. If this was request wide you could put it in the front controller during bootstrapping but this doesn’t look like the case.

Comment: I suggest putting in where it's needed. Since the ViewFactory takes care of the actual logic, there's no breach of any principle. Everything is isolated in it's own little world.

Comment: You are right, it was a contrived example. In reality there is a `ReportProcessor` class, that reads `Reports` from a queue. The `ReportProcessor` class creates the `View` class based on data in `Report`. Your above code would all be inside of the `ReportProcessor::handle(Report $report)` method. I would then need to DI `ViewFactory` into `ReportProcessor`, but this again hides the dependence on `View*`.

Comment: @ishegg @Andrew yes that is my question. This is not being run from a controller at all, rather a JobProcessor,  and that JobProcessor needs to have a `View*` class to render the report.  If I DI a `ViewFactory` the dependncy of `JobProcessor` on `View` is still not 100% explicit, but better than "newing" a View class.

Comment: Ohh, I see where you're going with this. Yah this changes things a little.

Comment: One option would also be to create a factory for the `View` and the `ReportGenerator`, something like `ViewReportFactory`. It's not by any means ideal but it will separate the reponsabilities better than the current setup. Let me write up an example and we'll see if that fits your needs.

Comment: Join me in [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166309/yisrael-dov-di) chat room for further discussion.